# {"Invalid column name 'Supplier_Address_Address_ID'."} in mvc 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I get the above message and I can see where the error is  here is the code I am new to MVC  please help 
 {"Invalid column name 'Supplier_Address_Address_ID'."}

```
public class Supplier
{
    [Key]
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    //[StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company Name is required")]
    [DisplayName("Company Name ")]
    public string Company_Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string Supplier_Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Surname Name is required")]
    [DisplayName("Surname Name")]
    public string Supplier_Last { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Address")]
    //[ForeignKey("Address_ID")]
    public int? Address_ID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Contact")]
    public int? Details_ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return Supplier_Name + ", " + Supplier_Last;
        }
    }

    public virtual Supplier_Address Supplier_Address { get; set; } 
}

public class Supplier_Address
{
    // [ForeignKey("Supplier")]
    [Key]
    public int Address_ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address Name is required")]
    [DisplayName("Address")]
    public string Address_1 { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("        ")]
    public string Address_2 { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pcode is required")]
    public int? Pcode { get; set; }

    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
}
```

this is my controller

```
public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
public DbSet<Supplier_Address> Supplier_Addresses { get; set; }

protected override void  OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modeBuilder)
{
    // this the  Suppler and  Address
    modeBuilder.Entity<Supplier>()
        .HasOptional(s => s.Supplier_Address)
        .WithMany();

    modeBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modeBuilder);
```

This is the error message:

> {"Invalid column name 'Supplier_Address_Address_ID'."}

Comment: You `ForeignKey` attribute value should be "Supplier_Address" (the name of the property), not "Address_ID".  Also, your `Supplier_Address` should contain a `Supplier_ID` so you can traverse backward.

Answer (score 0):

This is an EntityFramework issue
EntityFramework default codefirst db generation is very convention driven. You should keep the ForeignKey along with the Reference Object and the Corresponding Id Should be mentioned as an Id

```
[DisplayName("Address_ID")]
public int? Address_ID { get; set; }
public virtual Supplier_Address Supplier_Address { get; set; }
```

With this particular change I was able to get things working and tables were generated.